# Boxes messing up

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a website for a college task and I am really confused on why the `div` I am trying to create is not appearing.

It doesn't seem to work since I added the code for the three boxes, they are meant to be the same width as the three boxes.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rc4JK/4/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
        <div class="logo"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="button"> Home </div>
        <div class="button"> Destinations </div>
        <div class="button"> Make A Booking </div>
        <div class="button"> Things To Do </div>
        <div class="button"> Contact Us </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">
    content here
    </div>
    <div id="threeBoxContainer">
        <div id="deal_one"></div>
        <div id="deal_two"></div>
        <div id="deal_three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify on what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is hard to understand your question due its grammatical structure. However, if what you are trying to do is fit the three boxes into one line instead of have the third box drop down, your widths are too much. You can drop the 33% boxes to 32% and see that they'll fill the space.

Comment: Basically i want to make a div to go under the three boxes, but i also want the box to be the same width as them all togeather. But i am haveing trouble coding the box but when i do it seems to just leave a black line and the bottom of the page?

Comment: Sorry my grammar is horrific basically all i want is to create a box under the three boxes but it seems to look weird.

Comment: I posted a possible answer. Let me know if it doesn't work out or needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `box-sizing` property

```
#deal_one {
  /*Other Style */
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#deal_one {
  /*Other Style */
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#deal_three {
  /*Other Style */
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rc4JK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You Border-Width in each Box counts to the width.
Look at the Box-Model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Its because **css width only represents the content width**. Total width is the combination of padding, margin and border.

```
Total Width=ContentWidth+Padding+Border+Margin
```

So giving width to 33% and some margin,padding and border is making it actually greater than 33%. Reduce the width size to achieve the desire results. Around 30 or 31% will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you said in the comments, a possible answer:

HTML at the bottom:

```
<div id="threeBoxContainer">
    <div id="deal_one"></div>
    <div id="deal_two"></div>
    <div id="deal_three"></div>
</div>
<div id="bigbox"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#bigbox {
width: 98%;
height: 300px;
background-color:rgba(0, 95, 160, 1);
border: solid 2px black;
margin-top: 5%;
}
```

It seems to work for me. I can only get a solid line like you referred to if i leave the height out.

Comment: yeah it did seem to work thankyou, so what can i do to these three boxes to make them fill up the tiny space.

Comment: If it worked please accept the answer. As for the three boxes, they are affected by border width and if you use percentages they will be given pixel widths based on the available space. If you need to keep percentages, you can use 32.5% or along those lines - play with it to see what works. If you need it exact and don't care about keeping it percentages, give each one a pixel width that corresponds with the width it should fill. Use f12 in chrome to use the dev console to see what the pixel widths become for the percentages you give.